# Is it possible to trigger a screenshot from puppeteer with a click in the DOM of a loaded page?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to figure out a way to trigger a screenshot from the DOM of a page loaded in puppeteer.

Is there a simpler way than (possibly) having a value set in an element on the page when the screenshot is required, then doing an eval of that element for the text value and performing the screenshot within a loop (i.e. setInterval that checks every 5 seconds, for example)?

Comment: If you're clicking on the element via code e.g. `page.click()` wouldn't you just take the screenshot afterwards?

Comment: @ToddPrice I should have been clearer, in this use case a user isn't interacting with the DOM.  The loaded page (the client) has a socket connection with with a central host node app.  An administrative UI front-end lists all (socket) connected clients and can 'control' them (refresh, inspect, etc)... and one piece I needed was ability to capture a screenshot of the headless client browser.   I ended up solving it by having the admin UI send a socket id upstream (to host app) and setting a DOM element to 'screenshot' then doing an eval on that element and triggering the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using my socket.io connection to trigger a command to set a flag in a DOM element, then puppeteer evals that element when the flag is set, does the screenshot, then resets the flag.

Messy that I'm doing a re-eval of the element in puppeteer, every x seconds.  I'm now investigating whether puppeteer can have some type of event listener, and instead 'watch' the DOM element text and detect when it changes then fire the screenshot.

Comment: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.1&show=api-pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args Have you checked out this function yet? It does just what you want. It does long-polling at a default/configurable interval, with a function you specify returning true/false based on whatever conditions you want.